# Help me in studying "object recognition" in video?

Tags: c#, matlab, video-processing

Hi all
I need your help in studying  object recognition in video as this will be my new project in my faculty.

I had a previous study in "Computer Vision" field !

I just need your suggestions as " **Good Books, Web resources, Tutorials, others** " that will help me in my project.

my project will be in c# or Matlab

thanks

Comment: Ask your tutor; they ought to be able to point you at suggested reading.

Comment: please, I did not come here to get me back to my tutor .. I need real suggestions

Comment: @user: Your tutor really ought to be giving you useful pointers.  If not, they're not doing their job.

Answer (score 1):

Just a simple suggestion here. Break the problem down into small manageable chunks. Since your studying object recognition you will probably want to get most software off the shelf so you can focus on studying and not debugging.

If you are using mat lab. maybe you should look at this.

http://www.mathworks.com/products/image/

c# I would assume to have some awesome image processing library's now thanks to the xbox kinect.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/148251/How-to-Successfully-Install-Kinect-on-Windows-Open.aspx

and just another technology that is good for image processing is labview. If your faculty has licences and people that know it well to help you it may be another option.

http://www.ni.com/labview/whatis/?nipkw=LabVIEW&nicam=OceaniaZA-VI2009&nigrp=labview&nisrc=Google&niurl=&ninet=search

Answer (score 0):

It's not a simple subject so finding specific books/resources are unlikley. As Oli said, your tutor is a specialist, they should be able to point you to guides/reference material

Comment: And that was supposed to be a reply to the original post but it wouldn't let me.

Answer (score 0):

Check out scientific journals in the area of image processing such as [Pattern Recognition](http://www.elsevier.com/wps/find/journaldescription.cws_home/505619/description#description), [Pattern Recognition Letters](http://www.elsevier.com/wps/find/journaldescription.cws_home/505619/description#description), [Computer Vision and Image Understanding](http://www.elsevier.com/wps/find/journaldescription.cws_home/622809/description#description), [International Journal of Computer Vision](http://www.springerlink.com/content/100272/) etc, and books such as [Computer Vision And Image Processing](http://books.google.com.au/books?id=eSu5I9pU3rUC&printsec=frontcover&dq=computer+vision+and+image+processing&hl=en&ei=JFg-TaPEDoGevQP3xezEAw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=2&ved=0CEAQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q&f=false).